# Highcharts piechart labels going out of parent

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have small width of div and In that I want to show pie chart, But some labels of chart are going out of parent.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/cnanbsm0/) is what I did.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            spacingTop: 0,
            spacingBottom: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Brands",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                y: 56.33
            }, {
                name: "Chrome",
                y: 24.03,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }, {
                name: "Firefox",
                y: 10.38
            }, {
                name: "Safari",
                y: 4.77
            }, {
                name: "Opera",
                y: 0.91
            }, {
                name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
                y: 0.2
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 350px; margin: 0 auto;border:1px solid #F00;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@laxmikant-dange Do like this  http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/cnanbsm0/1/
Set desired width ,for your case I set datalabel's width 60 pixels.

```
 dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    width: '60px'//whatever width you want
                },
```

Comment: in your fiddle     dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
                         width: '60px'
                    }
                }

Comment: How can I use dynamic width based on dynamic data. As values are changing, sometime there may be 1 record or 10 records in data.

Comment: I reproduced that scenario by using 20 items instead of 5(chrome,safari etc) and observed that when number of categories increases highcharts show few label and other labels are shown on toolTip